# Is it efficient to use length() in loops?

Tags: performance, matlab, loops, time-complexity, variable-length

I have a lot of cases when I iterate over a vector in MATLAB,

so I do this :

```
len = length(vector)
for i=1:len
 do_something();
end
```

But this is just an intuition that says "prevent calling the `length()` function every time". Is it true? Or is it the same thing as this, in terms of time requirement :

```
for i=1:length(vector)
 do_something();
end
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You may measure it...

Comment: I can, but I also want to learn about MATLAB's way of compiling the code.

Comment: If you measure it, do try `numel` also. It may be faster than `length`

Comment: It would be very appreciated if you take a simple test and compare the elapse-times of the suggestions made above, you could use the ´tic toc´ function from matlab. And then show us the results :). And I would go for the `numel` too.

Comment: I doubt it would call it every time, I'm pretty sure the interpreter will first create a vector of 1:length(vector) and then only start the iterating process based on that vector. I can't imagine that you'd see any performance difference calling length before. It's not like you're calling it inside the loop itself, that might be different.

Comment: @Dan that's what I want to learn. I also think so, but I want to know :)

Comment: (@Dan I'm not sure about the interpreter creating the vector) I wonder if anything useful can be derived from this: The iterator can be given a larger number of steps than can be defined in a variable, for example (on my system) `crtl-c` whilst running `for a=1:inf;a+1;end;` yields *Warning: FOR loop index is too large. Truncating to 9223372036854775807.* however declaring `a=1:9223372036854775807` fails as **Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.**

Comment: @Dan, it doesn't work as simply as that. See my answer for more detail.

Comment: @RTL: 9223372036854775807 is `intmax('int64')` (and not `realmax()`). From that I think we can infer that Matlab's `for` loop implementation (for large values) internally uses a 64-bit `int` counter, probably to keep track of the number of iterations in the loop. Seems that you only get the warning if (B-A)/S in `for i = A:S:B` is large, not just if B is large. E.g. `for i = 1:1e24` gives that warning, but `for i = 1e25:1e25+5*eps(1e25)` and `for i = 1:1e24:1e25` do not.

Comment: @AndrewJanke interesting, I really should have recognised that as `intmax('int64')`, and +1 for internal 64bit loop counter... that sounds likely, especially as from my interpretation of the rest of your comment it seems dependent the number of elements not the values

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're concerned about performance or speed - don't worry about it, really. It will not make any appreciable difference. @David gives some timings in his answer that back this up.

In terms of aesthetics, for what it's worth I would normally write

```
for i = 1:numel(v)
    doSomething(v(i))
end
```

I tend to prefer `numel` to `length`, as `length` gives you the length of longest array dimension, rather than the length of the first dimension. If you're always sure it's a vector they're the same, but I try to avoid that assumption.

Of course, if I needed access to `numel(v)` separately, then it would be worth extracting it to an intermediate variable `vNum` and writing `for i = 1:vNum`.

If you're interested in the semantics of the `for` loop indices, it's more complex than you think. When you write `for i = 1:N`, MATLAB does not always simply create the vector `1:N` and then iterate through it. For example, you can write

```
for i = 1:realmax
    i
end
```

or

```
for i = 1:Inf
    i
end
```

or even

```
for i = Inf:-1:1
    i
end
```

and it will work (press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to escape). MATLAB doesn't create the loop indices as a vector in these case, and it couldn't, as it would be too large.

The parser has a more complex logic than that, with knowledge of several edge cases, and optimizations. Sometimes it will create the loop indices ahead of the loop, sometimes on the fly. I guarantee you will not be able to second-guess all the internals, unless you have access to the MATLAB source code.

Note also that the loop indices do not have to be a vector; if you supply an array, MATLAB loops through the columns. For example,

```
for i = magic(3)
    i
end
```

displays the columns of the array in turn. Similarly you can supply a cell array and it will iterate through the cells (NB the indices are the cells, not the elements within the cells).

For this reason, I would sometimes write

```
for vElement = v
    doSomething(vElement)
end
```

rather than the first pattern above using `numel`.

And of course, depending on the application, it may well be better to vectorize `doSomething` and call `doSomething(v)`.

One last thing - we're talking so far about integer indices really, but remember that the colon operator can have any increment, such as `pi:sqrt(2):10`; and remember that the colon operator is not the same as `linspace`, and will not give you the same answers.

Comment: How does `size` compare to the other two?

Comment: @excaza For arrays of built-in types, `numel(x)` is just the same as `prod(size(x))`. For arrays of user-defined classes, it is also this, unless you have overloaded `numel`.

Comment: Oh, duh. I'm so used to using `numel` along a specific dimension that I forgot what it's actually returning. Whoops.

Comment: @SamRoberts: One caveat: for user-defined classes, `numel(x)` (and `length(x)`) will ignore a user-defined `size(x)` method, so if you overload one, you effectively have to overload all the size-and-shape related functions to get consistent behavior. (I.e. `numel(x)` is more like `prod(builtin('size', x))`.)

Comment: +1, and a hearty second for preferring `numel` to `length`. I've run in to a bunch of bugs in practice where `length` was used in something that eventually got passed a non-vector input.

Comment: I thought that length also gives the longer dimension. Is it wrong ?

Comment: @CengizFrostclaw, yes, `length` gives the size of the longest dimension of the array (unless the array is empty, in which case it gives zero).

Answer (score 1):

I ran a test, first with JIT compilation on (I ran each test 3 times)

```
length(vector) 12.86 12.50 12.44    
N              13.00 12.52 12.55   
numel(vector)  12.83 12.55 12.56
```

and with JIT compilation off,

```
length(vector) 13.12 13.43 12.95   
N              12.54 13.04 13.00   
numel(vector)  12.57 12.92 12.72
```

I conclude that with JIT compilation on, it doesn't matter what you do, but without JIT then `numel` of `N` are best, but it doesn't seem to make a big difference. I can't explain this, and maybe this test is flawed, but there you go.

Here's the code:

```
clear
N=5e4;
A=rand(1e2);
tic()
vector=ones(1,N);
for i=1:length(vector)
    inv(A);
end
toc()
tic()
for i=1:N
    inv(A);
end
toc()
tic()
vector=ones(1,N);
for i=1:numel(vector)
    inv(A);
end
toc()
```

Comment: A possible explanation: `numel` is more "basic" than `length`  because `numel` directly measures the total bulk of memory used by the array; whereas `length` has to determine how that memory is organized into different dimensions, find the  "extent" along each dimension, and then give the maximum of those "extents".

Comment: There is quite a bit of variability, so I'm not sure how conclusive the results are. It could just be a bad test.

Comment: Well, computing the inverse takes much more time than what you want to measure. So I suggest replacing that line by a very simple operation. That way differences (if any) will stand out more

Comment: Also, the definition of the vector should be outside tic-toc, so that it doesn't affect

Comment: And in addition to what Luis Mendo said I'd also run test much more than three times (with average of all results). So few trials are affected by environment (CPU usage, other programs, disk I/O, Windows updates, tic/toc resolution and accuracy...)

Comment: @LuisMendo `numel` is implemented as though it were `prod(size(x))`, unless you have overloaded it for your own class. It isn't calculated via the memory used for the array. `length` also uses `size`, but returns the longest dimension of the array (basically `max(size(a))`, unless the array is empty, in which case it's always zero). Of course, they're all builtins, and don't directly call those MATLAB functions.

Comment: Based on Matlab's external interfaces doco and people's attempts to reverse-engineer the mxarray type, it looks like the number of elements and the size lists are each stored separately in the mxarray header. So `numel` probably reads nelements directly and is *slightly* simpler. But it doesn't matter – `numel`, `size`, `length`, `ndims` are all about as fast as a Matlab function can be, because those C-level operations are probably going to be swamped by the overhead of the M-code function call itself, even as a builtin.

Comment: @David: Matlab's statistical functions would let you test these results for significance to see if any conclusions could be drawn from them.

Answer (score 1):

They're the same. In the specific case of Matlab, don't worry about it: putting `length()` or any other function in the `for` initialization clause is always just as fast as evaluating it outside the loop, because `for` will only call it once either way. Your intuition is probably based on some other languages' `for` loops like C and Java, which have different behavior.

By definition, the Matlab `for` loop evaluates its argument expressions only once, at the beginning of the loop, to pre-compute a range or array of values for the loop index variable (`i`) to take on inside the loop passes. Unlike many other languages, Matlab's `for` does not re-evaluate some of the loop control statements each time through the loop. (This is also why assigning to the loop index variable inside the body of a Matlab `for` loop has no effect, where in C or Java it will allow you to "jump around" and alter the control flow.)

Have a read through the Matlab [for documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html). It could stand to be more explicit about it, but you'll notice it's defined in terms of the values that the expressions resolve to, and not the expressions themselves.

#### Syntax equivalence

A C `for` loop is defined to have this behavior.

```
/* C-style for loop */
for ( A; B; C; ) {
    ...
}

/* basically equivalent to: */
{
    A;
    while ( B ) {
        ....
        C;
    }
}
```

Functionally, Matlab's `for` loop syntax equivalence is more like this.

```
% Matlab for loop

for i = A:B
    ...
end

% basically functionally equivalent to:

tmp_X = A:B;         % A and B only get evaluated outside the loop!
tmp_i = 1;           % tmp_* = an implicit variable you have no access to
while tmp_i < size(tmp_X,2)
    i = tmp_X(:,tmp_i);
    ...
    tmp_i = tmp_i + 1;
end
```

And in practice, Matlab can optimize away the creation of the concrete array `tmp_X` in the case of primitive values. This decoupling of the loop body from the control expressions also helps support the parallel `parfor` loop used with the Parallel Computing Toolbox, because the value of the loop index variable for every loop iteration is known before the loop starts, and independent of the execution of any of the loop passes.

#### Demonstration

You can confirm this behavior yourself by using a function that has an observable side effect in the loop control clause.

```
function show_for_behavior

for i = 1:three(NaN)
    disp(i);
end

function out = three(x)
disp('three() got called');
out = 3;
```

You can see there was only one invocation for the whole loop.

```
>> show_for_behavior
three() got called
     1
     2
     3
```

#### Language reasons

Here's where I speculate a bit.

Beyond convenience, I suspect one of the reasons Matlab defines its `for` loop the way it does, instead of providing you the C style syntactic sugar over a regular `while` loop, is that it's tricky to get the index variable right due to floating-point roundoff. By default, the numeric loop variables you're working with are doubles, and for large values of `x` (around 10^15), `x + 1 == x`, because the relative precision at x (`eps(x)`) is greater than 1.

So if you do the naive `while`-loop transformation of `for i = A:B ... end` like this, you'll have an infinite loop, because at each step, `i = i + 1` will result in the same value of `i` due to rounding.

```
i = A;
while (i < B)
    ...
    i = i + 1;
end
```

To be able to perform loops over sequences of large values, you can compute the value range and number of steps, keep track of the loop index using a separate integer value, and construct the `i` value for each step using that counter and the step size, instead of incrementing a temporary variable on each pass. Something like this.

```
% original
for x = A:S:B; ...; end

% equivalent
nSteps = int64( ((B - A) / S) ) + int64(1);
i = int64(0);
while i < nSteps
    x = A + (S * double(i));
    ....
    i = i + int64(1);
end
```

You can only do this if the range min, max, and step are defined ahead of time for all passes, which isn't guaranteed with the more flexible `while`-loop form.

Note that in this case, for large A and B, x may have the exact same value for multiple iteration passes, but will eventually progress, and you'll get about as many loop iterations as you would expect if you were using infinite-precision values instead of approximate floating-point values. I suspect this is about what Matlab does internally in these cases.

Here's an example showing this behavior.

```
function big_for_loop(a)

if nargin < 1;  a = 1e20;  end
b = a + 4 * eps(a);
step = 15;

fprintf('b - a = %f\n', b - a);
fprintf('1 + (b - a) / step = %f\n', 1 + (b - a) / step);

last_i = a;
n = 0;
for i = a : step : b
    n = n + 1;
    if (i ~= last_i); disp('i advanced');  end
    last_i = i;
end
fprintf('niters = %d\n', n);
```

When I run this, i changes about as you would expect based on `eps` if this is how Matlab is doing the loop.

```
>> big_for_loop
b - a = 65536.000000
1 + (b - a) / step = 4370.066667
i advanced
i advanced
i advanced
i advanced
niters = 4370
```